# Show terms in archive page

Tags: loop, terms

I am trying to show terms of specific post type on archive page. I don't understand how to "echo" term name. Here is my code:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms("event_cat"); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      print term->name here
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_terms()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_terms/) retrieves terms in general, it makes no connection to a current post in loop.

What you need is one of template tags, which retrieve terms for the post. For example [`the_terms()`](http://queryposts.com/function/the_terms/):

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

      the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'event_cat' );

endwhile;
```

There are quite a few functions dealing with terms, depending on what you want to do with data.